# Exchange defragment

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange, defrag

A few days ago, we did an offline defrag on our exchange database. We have to make it to a new partition.

The command was:

```
"C:\Program Files\Exchsrvr\bin\eseutil.exe" /d /p /i "E:\Program Files\Exchsrvr\MDBDATA\priv1.edb" /t"G:\tempdfguj.edb"
```

We thought everything was ok. When the job was done, we copied the new files from G:\ to the original location, mounted the store and we happy...  But unfortunately, to this day we can't make online backups because we got the following error message:

> Information Store (6552) The streaming page read from the file "E:\Program Files\Exchsrvr\MDBDATA\priv1.STM" at offset 270336 (0x0000000000042000) for 464 (0x000001d0) bytes failed verification due to a page checksum mismatch.  The expected checksum was 3052248573 (0x00000000b5ed9dfd) and the actual checksum was 2309737967 (0x0000000089abcdef).  The read operation will fail with error -613 (0xfffffd9b).  If this condition persists then please restore the database from a previous backup. 
>   For more information, click http://www.microsoft.com/contentredirect.asp.

So I try to read, read, and read... Try everything...  `eseutil /R ; / mh / k`  ...so everything...  Now I decided to make a new defrag, but now I do it to STM file too, and I hope this new database will do the trick.

**So my question is about the correct steps:**

1. Dismount store, stop services, etc.
2. Make an offline backup
3. Run script
4. **May I delete the transaction logs?**
5. Copy back new files to original place.
6. Mount, start services...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Dismount store.
2. eseutil /mh - make sure it's in clean.
3. Move the logs somewhere else, mount the store.

if will not work, perform eseutil /p and then remove all the logs, make sure to leave the DB directory empty except edb and stm files, make sure logs are remove.
That should work.

Comment: Before you answer, i started something else. The defrag is interrupted, so we decided we victimize our STM file. We use MAPI so we have relative small STM file. (and we have backup e-mail server with KERIO, so if something lost, than we can open the mail on this server)

Comment: Very strange, but with this procedure, the EDB file grove up with almost 2 GB. Is this normal? (eseutil /p / createstm priv1.edb)

Comment: What's that "createstm" is for? Don't treat the files as separate. Look at it as one entity.

Comment: I separeted them 'coz i tougth eseutil only create an stm, and the edb doesn't change. Now the process ready. But now i don't know if i should mount it back or not. Coz' if i mount, and the peding mails arrive and than i should restore the original database...well, im goin crazy...I just want to fix the STM checksum issue...

Comment: I would start with the database in "clean" shutdown mode. So either restore from backup or somehow get the healthy database and follow the procedure I have outlined. It would be faster than trying to repair existing condition.

Comment: I have clean state. But i'm not sure if i delete the transaction logs then the STM cheksum mismatch will gone.

Comment: Now, i only one chance. Here is 4.25AM, i have 3 hour till work. If i copy back the original database and STM and logs -- this is 2.5 hour -- and something is wrong...

Comment: I don't think it will be gone.You need both, edb and stm files at the same point of time. I would suggest restore from backup.